# My Apologies usage

Tags: phrases

When you write a letter, and mention the phrase *my apologies*. How is this phrase used in a sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of one example that may be used in a letter:

> Dear So-and-so,
>
> My apologies that I did not write back to you earlier - I got sidetracked on the ELU forums.
>
> -rest of letter-

"My apologies" is effectively a more formal/posh way of saying "sorry".